# CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "attendance" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Employee"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Getting error when trying to get and populate data.

//Call

```
const db = require("../models");
const Employee = db.employee;
const Attendance = db.empAttendance;

exports.employeeAttendance = async (req, res) => {
  await Attendance.find()
        .populate("Employee")
        .exec((err, att)=>{
          res.send(att);
        })
};
```

//Model

```
const EmpAttendance = mongoose.model(
  "EmpAttendance",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    totalDays: Number,
    totalPresent: Number,
    totalAbsent: Number,
    employee: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Employee"
      }
  })
);

const Employee = mongoose.model(
  "Employee",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    employeeName: String,
    status: { type: Number, default: 1 },
  })
);
```

//Collection of EmpAttendance

[image]

//ERROR

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "attendance" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Employee"
    at model.Query.exec (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4498:21)
    at model.Query.Query.then (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4592:15)
    at exports.employee (G:\Dev\attendance-api\app\controllers\employee.controller.js:26:6)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at G:\Dev\attendance-api\app\middlewares\authJwt.js:19:5
    at G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12
    at getSecret (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as verify] (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at verifyToken (G:\Dev\attendance-api\app\middlewares\authJwt.js:14:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at param (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:360:14) {   messageFormat: undefined,   stringValue: '"attendance"',   kind: 'ObjectId',   value: 'attendance',   path: '_id',   reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
      at new ObjectID (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\bson\lib\bson\objectid.js:59:11)
      at castObjectId (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast\objectid.js:25:12)
      at ObjectId.cast (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:246:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1123:12)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType._castForQuery (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1601:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQuery (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1591:15)
      at ObjectId.SchemaType.castForQueryWrapper (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1568:20)

      at cast (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\cast.js:332:32)
      at model.Query.Query.cast (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4937:12)
      at model.Query.Query._castConditions (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:1975:10)
      at model.Query.<anonymous> (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2232:8)
      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOne] (G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\query\wrapThunk.js:16:8)
      at G:\Dev\attendance-api\node_modules\kareem\index.js:370:33
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11),   valueType: 'string' }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Try to change `.populate("Employee")` by `.populate("employee")` in lowercase. You have to indicate the field of `EmpAttendance` that you have populate.

Comment: Hello, I have changed "Employee" to "employee" as you said but it's still the same error.

Comment: Add the `_id` field in your `Employee` schema with `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId` as value.

Comment: I have found the issue. My routes have somehow conflicted "/api/employees" with "/api/employees/attendance". After I changed it to "/api/emp/attendance" it worked. Thanks for your help.